# Google Stopped creating Google Meet link while creating event using Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-meet

From today Google has stopped creating Google meet Url while creating an Event.

- Event is created, however meet url is not created.
- This code was working since last 3 month.

```
    ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
    ConferenceSolution conferenceSolution = new ConferenceSolution();
            
    CreateConferenceRequest createRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
    ConferenceSolutionKey conferenceSolutionKey_ = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
    conferenceSolutionKey_.setType("hangoutsMeet");
    
    createRequest.setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSolutionKey_);
    createRequest.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    conferenceData.setConferenceId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    
    conferenceData.setCreateRequest(createRequest);
    event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);
```

Note : I have not created  EntryPoint
Is there anything updated from Google side and therefore this code is not working ?

Our production code has been impacted due to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Google has made some changed and it was stopped creating Google Meet url ( Event was created ) Base on input form Google Engineer it is require to set ConferenceDataVersion = 1. However for Java API that is not just enough.
Here it is complete solution of creating Calendar Event + Meet url

```
    Event event = new Event()
            .setSummary("Your summary")
            .setLocation("Your location")
            .setDescription("Your description");
    
    ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
    ConferenceSolution conferenceSolution = new ConferenceSolution();
    
    CreateConferenceRequest createRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
    ConferenceSolutionKey conferenceSolutionKey_ = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
    conferenceSolutionKey_.setType("hangoutsMeet");
    
    createRequest.setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSolutionKey_);
    createRequest.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    
    List<EntryPoint> entryPoints = new ArrayList<EntryPoint>();
    EntryPoint entryPoint = new EntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setEntryPointType("video");
    entryPoints.add(entryPoint);
    conferenceData.setEntryPoints(entryPoints);
    conferenceData.setCreateRequest(createRequest);
    conferenceSolution.setKey(conferenceSolutionKey_);
    conferenceData.setConferenceSolution(conferenceSolution);
    
    event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);
    
    // Build your calenderService using Scope + AccessToken
    Calendar calenderService = getCalenderService();
    
    // calendarId  = Your private or public calendarId. Default option = "primary"
    event = calenderService.events().insert("calendarId", event).setConferenceDataVersion(1).execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

#### This appears to be a bug!

There is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which detail the same kind of behaviour:

- [No conference data is received when adding an event via Calendar API.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167260246)

Google does seem to know about this issue already and you can follow bug updates using the above link.

You can also hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned pages which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

Answer (score 1):

Add the type "video" to the "entryPoints":

```
 "entryPoints": [
   {
     "entryPointType": "video"
   }
 ]
```